# perl how to import utility file?

Tags: perl, syntax

In the perl, how to include a util file ? for example, I have a file "util.pl" , inside which has a function. then I want to include / import that file, how to do it ?

```
main.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

main();

sub main{
    my_funtion("start processing feed");
}

---------
util.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub my_funtion {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pl script you need.

```
require "util.pl";
```

Near the top (after `use strict`) of your `main.pl` script.

Using `.pm` files, packages, and the `use` statement is probably "better". But the above will solve the question you asked.

Comment: you need to add the statement "1;" at the end of util.pl

Comment: you can also use "do 'util.pl'". But as sodved mentioned do some research about packages and use them

Comment: yes, as Aki said, I need add "1;", but why I need this ? why I can't put that line after "use warnings" ?

Comment: You can actually put it anywhere before you use it. So after `use warnings` is fine, probably better. You need the `1;` at the end of the file because `require` needs the last statement in the file to have a "true" value to be successful. So can actually be any expression which is not 0, `undef`, or the empty string. The convention however is `1` as thats the simplest "true" value. One of the "things" (sometimes good, sometimes bad) about perl is there's 100 ways to do anything